# Azure Resource Management List Virtual Guests /providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2015-06-15

Tags: azure

Below mentioned API is used to invoke all virtual machines :

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2015-06-15

In the response of virtual machines, virtual machine Id  as mentioned here
**"id": "/subscriptions/subscriptonId/resourceGroups/AGILITY/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ProxyDontDelete10001",**
in which resource group name is in Capital Letters (AGILITY) and if we invoke another rest api using this ID to get the instance view details it's not working.

/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/i-00000009/InstanceView

```
{
"value": [
  {
"properties": {
"vmId": "7eb8dca3-dacf-4c51-b079-a508bf6d02b9",
"hardwareProfile": {
"vmSize": "Basic_A0"
},
"storageProfile": {
"osDisk": {
"osType": "Linux",
"name": "ProxyDontDelete10001",
"createOption": "FromImage",
"image": {
"uri": "https://blob.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/SM-RHEL6.7s-x64-9.2.r1664-20150801.vhd"
},
"vhd": {
"uri": "https://blob.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/ProxyDontDelete10001_ee751938-8d5c-468b-a36f-63e5332405cf.vhd"
},
"caching": "ReadWrite"
},
"dataDisks": [],
},
"osProfile": {
"computerName": "ProxyDontDelete10001",
"adminUsername": "admin",
"linuxConfiguration": {
"disablePasswordAuthentication": false
},
"secrets": [],
},
"networkProfile": {
"networkInterfaces": [
  {
"id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/testProxyDontDelete10001_ee751938-8d5c-468b-a36f-63e5332405cf"
}
],
},
"provisioningState": "Succeeded"
},
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"location": "westus",
"id": "/subscriptions/subscriptonId/resourceGroups/AGILITY/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ProxyDontDelete10001",
"name": "ProxyDontDelete10001"
},
```

Comment: this question is really hard to understand, can you edit it so we can answer it?

Comment: edited and added details

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but resource group name is **not** case sensitive, so doing to:

```
/subscriptions/subscriptonId/resourceGroups/agility/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ProxyDontDelete10001
```

should also work.

Comment: In response i am getting resource group name as in capital letters AGILITY and if i invoke rest api call using the same it's not working. /subscriptions/subscriptonId/resourceGroups/AGILITY/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ProxyDontDelete10001

Comment: well, you didn't really show how you are calling the API, my API calls work independent of casing

Comment: Refer the api error response which clearly shows https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/AGILITY/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/i-ProxyDontDelete10001/InstanceView?api-version=2015-06-15  Error Response : {
"error": {
"code": "ResourceNotFound",
"message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/Prox‌​yDontDelete10001' under resource group 'AGILITY' was not found."
}
}

Comment: your VM id is `"/subscriptions/subscriptonId/resourceGroups/AGILITY/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ProxyDontDelete10001"` and you query some nonsense `/subscriptions{subscriptionId}/resourceG‌​roups/AGILITY/provid‌​ers/Microsoft.Comput‌​e/virtualMachines/i-‌​00000009`

Comment: I have multiple VM's. if required i can share you full response. If it's working why i will post question here.

Comment: do please. I cannot repro this. @vijay